# Import config on Drush install with config in non-standard directory

Tags: drush, 9, configuration, installation

I've got a site set up with its config sync in a directory outside of web root; specifically ../config/sync (relative to the Drupal root). I have that path set for `$settings['config_sync_directory']` in sites/default/settings.php. All is well.

I'm now experimenting with how I can import that configuration into another site while installing. In another directory, I copied over my config directory as well as composer.json and ran `composer install`. Now I see that Drush has the `--existing-config` flag, but that results in "Existing configuration directory not found or does not contain a core.extension.yml file." So I'm guessing it's not seeing that my config sync directory is in a non-default place. But I do not see an option to specify the path to where that config really is, and before installation, there's no sites/default/settings.php in which to set it in code. I see that Drush has a `-D/--define` option to set configuration options, but from what I can tell that's only for config that would be in YAML files and not for settings that'd be in settings.php. So I'm out of ideas.

Is what I'm trying to do impossible? I'm not against temporarily moving my config directory to wherever Drush/Drupal will look for it (where is that exactly?) and then moving it back when done but I'd rather not. Should I just install first without trying to import config, tweak settings.php, and then import the config in separate steps?

Comment: Is it a clone of the same site?

Comment: You just create settings.php yourself (and even version-track it) while having it include the settings.local.php (not version-tracked) where you put the database credentials.

Comment: Another option is to just do a minimal install and then import the config after the install is complete.  I run my CI tests this way-- start from fresh DB, install Drupal, then import config from a custom directory.

Comment: You don't even need a full settings.php - DB credentials can still be supplied in UI/CLI if they are missing in settings.php. You just need to add the `$settings['config_sync_directory']` line beforehand

Comment: @leymannx That is the goal, yes.

Comment: @Hudri What do I add that line to, though?

Comment: Copy default.settings.php to settings.php and put it in settings.php, or a file included from settings.php like leymannx mentioned @GarrettAlbright

Comment: If the config is not from a minimal profile, the install from config won't work though. Instead do a standard install, set the site UUID and then import the config.